# Decoding an MD5 hash where I already know most of the string

Tags: brute-force-attack, md5

Let's say my friend has made an md5 hash of an email address and sent it to me. The email address will be something like 'jessica_XXXX@gmail.com', and I know it begins with 'jessica_' and ends with '@gmail.com'

Does software exist that would allow me to bruteforce the middle part, which is only four unknown characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [hashcat](https://hashcat.net/hashcat/) is great for this.